# how can core data values be used in if statements

Tags: swift

I have a value that goes up by one every time a question is correctly answered (learn_streak) I am trying to check if this value is bigger than a value in core data (bsVoLearn, type: Int64)

the aim is to check whether or not the learn_streak is larger than bsVoLearn and if it is to set bsVoLearn to learn_streak

I have tried this in a function within content view

```
if learn_streak >= student.bsVoLearn { // error on this line
                let student = Student(context: moc)
                student.bsVoLearn = Int64(learn_streak)
                try? moc.save()
            }
```

however this didn't work (the error is that it can't find student in scope)

Comment: Please be a *minimum* specific: **what** didn't work?? Is it because you are trying to compare an `Int` with an `Int64`?? What else have you tried?

Comment: @HunterLion the error is that it can't find student in scope, I am at a loss for what else to try

Comment: `student` as the object you use in the `if` condition? You are not making easy for us...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson its not about the if condition it's about checking if the 'learn_streak' is larger than 'bsVoLearn'. if you could do this easier differently that would be great

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't understand what you mean, there is still the error

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how could the error be solved?

Comment: You defined `student` inside the closure, so *after* it has evaluated the condition. If you don't define a `student` *before* the condition, the compiler will not be able to understand what student you are referring to.

Comment: So finally you tell us where the error is. There is no way to tell why you get that error since there is not enough code to understand what is going on. You are using a variable `student` that the compiler doesn't know what it is and how/where it is defined. This has nothing to do with Core Data but is a basic programming issue.

Answer (score -2):

here is the solution I have found,

```
 let student = Student(context: moc)
                if learn_streak >= student.bsVoLearn {
                    
                    student.bsVoLearn = Int64(learn_streak)
                    try? moc.save()
                }
```

Comment: In this solution you are always creating a new `Student` object and then use that new object in your comparison, so this code doesn't look correct. Do you really want to create a new Student object every time learn_streak is increased, don't you rather want to update bsVoLearn for an existing student?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).